# Mobile NavBar Bootstrap with left bar icon and right aligned icons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4. I'd like to create a android like navbar with bar icon item to be on the far left. exactly as per the image
And other icons on the right side of the navbar.

I've tried applying ml-auto, mx-auto, mr-auto, pull-right, etc. Nothing does what I want.

[image]

mx-auto was nice for the small screen. It put the navbar-brand centered when the hamburger menu is there. However, I need something that works when the regular menu is there.

What i have tried is below but the items break on different phone screen sizes.

```
<header class="expo-mobile-header">
  <nav class="navbar shadow-sm sticky-top navbar-light bg-light navbar-expand-sm">
    <button type="button" aria-label="Toggle navigation" aria-controls="navbar-toggle-collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="navbar-toggler border-0 mr-0 px-0 float-right" style="font-size: 1em;">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button> 
    <a target="_self" href="#" class="navbar-brand">NavBar</a> 
    <button type="button" aria-label="Toggle navigation" aria-controls="navbar-toggle-collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="navbar-toggler border-0 float-left" style="font-size: 1em;"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button> 
    <button type="button" aria-label="Toggle navigation" aria-controls="navbar-toggle-collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="navbar-toggler border-0" style="font-size: 1em;"><i class="fas fa-bookmark"></i> 
    </button>
 </nav> 
</header>
```

Here is my code:

Comment: the code doesnt work to display anything?

Comment: @Stanley the items misbehave on different mobile screen size

Comment: i get a blank page with title navbar and no icons or anything, i have linked bootstrap 4

Comment: @Stanley shud use font awwesome too.!!

Comment: still nothing, even inspecting element and trying different queries gives blank webpage. I do get the small background color of the header though

Comment: Nevermind got an error refusing to import it. give me a few minutes

Comment: @GeorgeAlvis - please clarify how you expect the navbar to look on non-mobile screens? Where are the other nav items? What are you trying to toggle with the hamburger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"></meta>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"></meta>

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"></meta>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css"></link>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></link>

    <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-primary">
        <div class="col-4">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="fas fa-bars text-white"></span>
                    </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 text-white align-left">Title</div>
        <div class="col-1"> </div>
        <div class="col-1"><span class="fa fa-search text-white"></span></div>
        <div class="col-1"><span class="fa fa-heart  text-white"></span></div>
        <div class="col-1"><span class="fas fa-ellipsis-v  text-white"></span></div>



    </nav>

    <div class="pos-f-t  bg-primary">
        <div class="collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
            <div class="bg-lightp-4">
                <h4 class="text-white">Collapsed content</h4>

                <span class="text-muted">
                    Toggleable via the navbar brand.
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

see:https://jsfiddle.net/sugandhnikhil/Leatv5b3/
Enjoy!!! Thanks