# Changing color of Nav Bar on Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar

I want to change the font color of the Nav Bar to white, but I'm having trouble identifying the correct CSS class to call out to do so. 'Navbar' on the top left is already white because of Bootstraps' CSS, but I want to change 'Contact', 'Portfolio' and 'About' to white also.

HTML

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#"> Contact <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
    .nav-item{
        color:white
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-primary">
```

and add

```
text-white
```

Comment: This doesn't change the text to white, as requested.

Comment: check this!!!!!!

Comment: check this for refernece https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61169561/mobile-navbar-bootstrap-with-left-bar-icon-and-right-aligned-icons/61174293#61174293

Comment: @terrymorse i guess you did asked for it neither did you check my answer  commenting negative about it

Comment: "navbar-light" sets text color to black, not white. Adding "text-white" to every link will work, but it is a brute-force technique. No different than setting `style="color: white` on every link.

Comment: @terrymorse **IT WILL WORK**

Comment: Yes it will work. But it requires markup on every link. Rather inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

In your main "nav class" you have select "bg-primary" try this

Answer (score 0):

For overall text color in a navbar, there are two classes: `navbar-dark` and `navbar-light`.

`navbar-dark` has a base color of white. `navbar-light` has a base color of black, with a 90% opacity.

Navbar links have reduced opacity, so they will neither be completely black or completely white.

To force all link colors to white, you can target the `.nav-link` rule, like this:

```css
    .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
      color: white;
    }
```

A working example:

```html
<!-- navbar-dark with link text forced to white -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- insert this style *after* linking Bootstrap -->
<style>
  .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: white;
  }
</style>

<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler mr-5" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#"> Contact <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```